How can I set up vault with TLS in dev mode via helm
I am trying to test a helm deployment that interacts with Hashicorp Vault. I am currently setting up TLS encryption and want my tests to run using TLS against the vault server while it's in dev mode (for testing). I have not been able to get this to work so far and have tried a few variations on the vault configuration.
My current configuration (test-values.yaml):
injector:
  enabled: false
global:
  enabled: true
  tlsDisable: false
server:
  extraEnvironmentVars:
    # Attempt to have dev server listen somewhere else while the TCP listener listens on 8200
    # This results in "connection refused" errors. Maybe the standalone config is not used??
    # have tried with and without
    VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0:8400
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/test-certs/ca.crt
    # tell vault to use https... this hasn't seemed to do anything really, have tried with and without
    VAULT_ADDR: https://127.0.0.1:8200
  extraVolumes:
    - type: secret
      name: test-certs
  dev:
    enabled: true
  standalone:
    enabled: true
    config: |
      listener "tcp" {
        address = "[::]:8200"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
        tls_disable = 0
        tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/test-certs/tls.crt"
        tls_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/test-certs/tls.key"
      }
      storage "file" {
        path = "/vault/data"
      }

My most recent attempt (based on this comment) is setting the VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS to some unused port so that the TCP listener can handle traffic on 8200, however, this caused the connection to be refused.

Error enabling: Post "https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/mounts/transit": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused

This makes me think maybe in dev mode the standalone config I have defined is ignored?
Beyond that everything else I have tried has resulted in the following HTTP error

Error enabling: Post "https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/mounts/transit": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

From what I've read, this is because in dev mode, vault doesn't use tls by default. Enabling tls via helm values.yaml doesn't seem to effect dev mode (from what I've tried so far). I see when using vault directly or in docker there are ways of making this work, however those same methods don't seem to be available for the helm deployment (as far as I can see).
The errors above are a result of running the following command, but would occur for any vault command.
kubectl exec vault-0 -- vault secrets enable transit

So.. Is it possible to deploy vault via helm into k8s in dev mode with tls enabled? How can I configure tls in dev mode when deploying to k8s via helm? Any help getting this working would be much appreciated!
Steps to reproduce:
# certificates will need to be generated
kubectl create secret generic test-certs \
  --from-file=ca.crt=./ca.crt \
  --from-file=tls.crt=./tls.crt \
  --from-file=tls.key=./tls.key

helm repo add hashicorp https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com
helm install vault hashicorp/vault -f test-values.yaml

